# How to set batch size in one micro-batch of spark structured streaming

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I am reading streaming data from Kafka source, but all the data from kafka is read in a single micro batch.

```
spark.readStream.format("kafka").option("kafka.bootstrap.servers",bootstrap_servers).option("subscribe", topics).option("startingOffsets", "earliest").load()
```

Which parameter or option is used to set max batch size in one micro-batch of spark structured streaming?

Answer (score 3):

use `maxOffsetsPerTrigger` to limit the no of messages.

as per spark doc "maxOffsetsPerTrigger  - Rate limit on maximum number of offsets processed per trigger interval. The specified total number of offsets will be proportionally split across topicPartitions of different volume."

Comment: It does not work properly. In my case, kafka has ~1K records and `maxOffsetsPerTrigger` set as 100, still I was getting 100+ micro batches and most of the batches are empty except 2 / 3 batches.

Comment: How many partitions does your topics has? maxOffsetsPerTrigger is per partition.

Comment: Topic has 5 partitions